# Download google drive folder's file via wget

Tags: google-drive-api, wget

I want to download google drive folders file via wget how it is possible?

I have folder **version** in google drive and in that version folder all version apk file of my mobile app.

Folder tree like this

```
Version : -> mobileapp1.apk
          -> mobileapp2.apk
          -> mobileapp3.apk
```

And I want to download by passing version name. Is it possible with google drive and wget? I have already make folder **Public on the web - Anyone on the Internet**

Comment: See this answer for a way to download via `curl` (works as of 2018): https://stackoverflow.com/a/32742700/

Answer (score 0):

You can download old version files using wget. In order to download old version files, Access token, File ID and Revision ID are required as the materials. The methods for retrieving the materials are follows. wget is used for all methods.

#### 1. Access token

Reference : https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

This is my old answer related to retrieving access token from Google OAuth2. [Refresh Google drive access__token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815450/refresh-google-drive-access-token/42822060#42822060) If this is useful for you, I'm glad.

#### 2. File ID

In order to retrieve file ID, it searches it from file name using `drive.files.list`.

```
wget -q --header='Authorization: Bearer ### Access token ###' \
    'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=name="### FileName ###"&fields=files(id,name)' \
    -O out.txt
```

By this, you can find `FileID` for the FileName in the `out.txt`. If there are several files with same name, please select one of them.

Reference : https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list

#### 3. Revision ID

In order to retrieve revision ID, it retrieves revision list for the `FileID` using `drive.revisions.list`.

```
wget -q --header='Authorization: Bearer ### Access token ###' \
    'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/### FileID ###/revisions?fields=revisions(id%2CmodifiedTime)' \
    -O out.txt
```

By this, you can find `RevisionID` for the FileID in the `out.txt`. Please select revision ID you want.

Reference : https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/list

#### 4. File for Revision ID

Retrieves File for Revision ID using `drive.revisions.get`.

```
wget -q --header='Authorization: Bearer ### Access token ###' \
    "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/### FileID ###/revisions/### RevisionID ###?alt=media" \
    -O outputfilename
```

By this, a file with name of `outputfilename` can be retrieved.

Reference : https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/get

Comment: Hello @Tanaikem I'm a newbie in scripting. Can you tell me how to download file/folder from google drive by using wget please? I'm using Ubuntu

Comment: @Gennaro Arguzzi Hello. Unfortunately, I cannot answer your question of `Hello @Tanaikem I'm a newbie in scripting. Can you tell me how to download file/folder from google drive by using wget please? I'm using Ubuntu`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So how about posting it as new question? By this, it will help users think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I posted a question about that. I hope to find a solution as soon as possible. Thank you very much for your willingness

Comment: @Gennaro Arguzzi Thank you for your quick reply.