# Unable to locate HEAD deployment - GAS IDE

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, web-applications, version

I have a simple web app in GAS that consumes data via the doPost() function and writes some rows to a spreadsheet. My goal is to test the app using Postman and keep the code always in sync without having to redeploy a new version every single time.
The app is set to "Execute as me" and is authorized to be run by "Anyone".

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments) states that

> The head deployment is always in sync with most recently saved code.
> For example, if you create a versioned deployment and then modify your
> code, the head deployment reflects those changes, while the versioned
> deployment remains intact.

After hours of trying, I'm still unable to locate the HEAD deployment and keep the code in sync without having to create a versioned deployment for every tiny change in the code.

The head deployment ID is visible under Test Deployments but any Postman calls to /dev fail and I'm getting the "unauthorized" error.
I also can't see any deployments named HEAD under "Manage deployments".
For  versioned deployments, the URLs ending in "exec" work perfectly but those aren't synced to the latest changes in the code and I have to redeploy every time.
Any ideas here?

Comment: All that is expected :) You may need to send access tokens for the `/dev` endpoint.

Comment: In your situation, is this report useful? https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#how-to-use-dev-mode-from-outside or https://tanaikech.github.io/2022/12/07/workaround-reflecting-latest-script-to-deployed-web-apps-created-by-google-apps-script-without-redeploying/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54190322/

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, your thorough explanation is a life saver. On a hunch, I actually tried including the token in the Auth header but forgot to call Drive.getFiles()

Comment: Thank you for replying. When those were useful, I'm glad. As an important point, when an error occurs by including the access token in the request header, please try to include the access token in the query parameter instead of the request header. By this, there is a case that the issue can be removed.